# How to prevent ConcurrentModificationException?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I have some code which allows a server to generate some terrain, and then send that data to a separate client program via datagram packets. The pseudocode for the client receiving this data is as follows:

```
-client sends SYN message to server
-server responds with ACK message (using 2-step SYNACK)
-client sends request for terrain from x=0 to x=32
-server responds with 32 seperate packets, one for each x (to keep packet size small)
-client receives packets and puts data into an ArrayList
```

In my current solution the client is running two simultaneous threads, a graphics thread for drawing the data to the screen, and a packet receiver thread (as the .receive() function in a datagram socket hangs until a packet is received).

Currently if one of the 32 packets of terrain arrive whilst the graphics update method is running then a concurrent modification exception occurs.

I have thought of two possible solutions:

1. Save the packet when it arrives and handle it in the graphics thread (however this may cause a packet to be lost if they arrive too quickly when graphics hang).
2. Use a variable to cause the packet receiver to hang which can be set in the graphics update.

Neither of these solutions seem ideal though, and both have their flaws. Is there a good solution to my problem, and if not then which one of the above solutions would be best to use?

Comment: Side question: You're not guaranteed to get all the data if you use UDP and datagram packets, correct? So why use this?

Comment: Question 2: What type of GUI? And have you considered showing pertinent code?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels 1) Yes, so to fix that I'm planning on using acknowledgement packets, but I will implement that later, regardless of how I handle the data checking I need to ensure that the code doesn't crash. 2) JFrame GUI displaying a Graphics2D with a BufferedImage backbuffer. There's a lot of code spread across a lot of classes, I will edit the post to include the relevant code when I'm next able to.

Comment: Peter Lawrey has your solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest using a Queue to pass data between thread rather than a List or a Set.

If you use a concurrent queue like ArrayBlockingQueue or ConcurrentLinkedQueue neither of these will trigger a CME.

Note: I suggest you avoid using an Iterator but instead call `take()` or `poll()` to extract events from the queue.